# Select column 1 to 10 of ActiveCell row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

this is regarding a macro in an excel.

While a combination of keys are pressed (i.e. the macro is triggered), I need to do some format changes to the columns 1 to 10 of the row that has the ActiveCell.

At the moment I have am selecting the entire row

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
```

However, I need to select only the row 1 to 10. I think it ought to be something like

```
ActiveCell.Range(1, 10).Select
```

But that does not work.

Just to be clear, I have read about

```
ActiveCell.Offset(5, -4).Select
```

But that is not going to work in my case. The ActiveCell could be any column of the row and hence a hardcoded offset is not going to help.

So, the excel gurus there, I am hoping this is a quick stuff, just that somehow I can't find the answer. Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is always columns 1 to 10 (i.e. A to J) then this ought to work:

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":J" & ActiveCell.Row)
```

For example if the activecell is `M14` then this will select the range `A14:J14`. You can then format this how you like.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, this works. And it is better than what I had posted as an interim answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is what I did, and it works.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10)).Select
```

In my mind this is sort of a hacky way. If there is anything better, please respond. Till we get something better, I guess this is the best answer for people who come looking for the anwer, after me.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(1,10).select
```

Answer (score 0):

if applicable..  spent alot of time to find,  needed a more programmable - automated answer, for results - work on 1 line.

```
        Dim N7 As String: N7 = RANGE("N7")    'workcell N7 shows eg:  A:J    
        Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.row), RANGE(N7).Columns).Select   'YES ANSWER

    'other:
        If application.Max(Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.row), RANGE(N7).Columns)) > 0 Then

      MsgBox "YES" & Space(10), vbQuestion  ', "title": end if    & vbCr &
Else: MsgBox "NO" & Space(10), vbQuestion: End If ', "title": end if    & vbCr &

'Cells(ActiveCell.row, J6).OFFSET(, 1).RESIZE(, 6).Select    'YES: offset works on immediate cols for 1 row
'Cells(ActiveCell.row, J6).RESIZE(, 5).Select                'yes on 4 immediate cols for 1 row   (row, col)
'Cells(ActiveCell.row, B5).select
```

workcell N7 has:
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",$A7),"$",""),ROW(),"")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",$J7),"$",""),ROW(),"")